# insert dados em múltiplas tabelas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira, entidade-relacionamento, chave-primária

Iniciei um projeto ao mesmo tempo que iniciei os estudos em banco de dados. Criei uma tabela só para telefone de clientes e outra tabela para todos os dados do cliente, inclusive o telefone como foreign key. na tabela de telefone criei uma primary key e usei o id do cliente como foreign key.. Quando vou inserir dados na tabela cliente exige que a tabela telefone já tenha primary key. As tabelas foram criadas sem problema. porém quando vou inserir dados, em qualquer que seja a tabela, tenho problema. como devo fazer?

```
table_clientes(
idcliente int auto_increment,
nome varchar(10),
idfone int,
primary key(idcliente),
foreign key(idfone) references table_fone(idfone)
)

table_fone(
idfone int auto_increment,
fone1 varchar(10) not null,
fone2 varchar(10),
celular varchar(10),
primary key(idfone),
idcliente int,
foreign key (idcliente) references tbclientes (idcliente)
)
```

Comment: Primeiro, você deverá possuir um FK em cada tabela, sem isso não dá pra continuar, nem que isto seja apenas símbolico. Após, crie os registros na tabela primária e após o registro atrelado a tabela secundária.

Comment: Creio que você deveria repensar seu modelo de dados.

Comment: @JaksonFischer, então eu deveria criar uma PF(sem valor) e utiliza-lá como FK na outra tabela? Porque eu já criei uma FK em cada tabela.

Comment: @anonimo, você pode me explicar onde meu modelo de dados falhou? assim, talvez, possa repensar.

Comment: Se você só tem um telefone de cada tipo por cliente, não precisa de uma tabela separada para telefones. E se tiver mais de um, não faz sentido FK na tabela de clientes. A FK deve estar em apenas uma das pontas.

Comment: @bfavaretto, na verdade a tabela telefone tem fone1,fone2,ramal,celular.. e assim por diante. Então eu devo criar apenas uma tabela telefone com o idcliente para identificar e realizar query nessa tabela para saber o telefone?

Comment: Por isso eu disse "um telefone de cada tipo". Desse jeito que você modelou cada linha na tabela é um "pacote" com potencialmente 3 números de telefone. Mas não é o único jeito de modelar. O princípio é, se você determina que cada cliente só pode ter até 3 telefones, o mais simples é criar 3 colunas de telefone na tabela de clientes. Se o máximo de telefones por cliente for indeterminado, aí sim a única maneira é usar uma tabela separada. entendeu?

Comment: @bfavaretto, entendi. Faz sentido o que você falou. Vou rever minha modelagem. Muito obrigada pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao referenciar uma foreign key você deve possuir antecipadamente o id do registro que fará a relação.
Em sua modelagem as duas tabelas possuem foreign key uma para a outra. Dessa forma uma impede a outra de inserir, pois precisa ter o id da outra.

Não é necessário usar foreign key nas duas tabelas. É preciso referenciar apenas uma delas.

---

Bom, então qual tabela eu uso o foreign key então?

Vai depender de qual relação vai querer ter.

Por exemplo:

**Cliente pode ter mais que um telefone?** Então a foreign key vai na tabela telefone, dizendo a quem pertence aquele telefone

**Telefone pode ter mais que um cliente?** Então a foreign key vai na tabela cliente, dizendo qual telefone o cliente possui.

**Cliente pode ter apenas um telefone?**

Nessa condição existem duas formas de serem feitas:

1. Criar um campo telefone na tabela cliente.
2. Usar a foreign key na tabela telefone e controlando a regra via
   código.

Comment: Concordo contigo, Anderson. Eu estava usando as FK nas duas tabelas. Tive que refazer minha modelagem de dados. Muito obrigada.